# how to get data only from one of the table and the join table in many to many relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

[image]

I have similar many to many relationship as between stock and category as is shown in the above figure. And therefore we have a join table called stock_category.

Entities are as follows:

```
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID")
    private Integer stockId;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "stock_category", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private Set<Category> categories;

....
```

and

Category.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {


@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
private Integer categoryId;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories")
private Set<Stock> stocks ;

............
```

So basically in our project we have two entities which are related in many to many relationship (most of the times  bidirectional) with each other. Also, the I do not have entity of the join table.

My question:

1) How do I only fetch data by joining stock and stock_category(join table)? I do not want to join third table. Since i do not have entity of the join table I am forced to join third table as well which is causing performance issues in our project. We are using hibernate criteria. But I have tried doing the same using spring data jpa, native query, hql, etc but was not able to achieve.

2) Can I get data only and only from the join table i.e. stock_category without joining any additional tables?

Comment: The join table doesn't have any information. So what data would you need to get from it? What's the actual use-case? Give a real example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Join table contains linking  between stock and category which is very important information. Use case: I had Stock bean ie. i had stock ID and i wanted to find categories Ids linked with this stock id. So basically i wanted to find the list of category Ids (not the list of actual category bean) associated with the supplied stock.

Comment: `select category.id from Stock stock join stock.categories category where stock.id = :stockId`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this solution is not working and a big query is formed which involves all three tables (which i want to avoid - because i just need data from stock table and stock_category join table). I tried this in hibernate criteria since our project uses it. Also i have list of stock ids and therefore i expect list of stock beans and each stock bean should contain  set of categories containing only and only categoryIds and not other unnecessary information related to categories.